# How to show the most nested errors first in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2010.

Typical case -- solution with two projects A (library) and B (main project). Of course B depends on A. Let's say I made an error in A (library). As effect I get million errors from main project and then at the end error from library.

I don't have to explain how tiresome it is, gcc for example always shows the most nested errors first, because it is obvious that error in most used part of software can be the cause of all other errors.

So how to make Visual Studio to show the most nested errors first? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not arguing that you don't get errors from both, but surely if B is dependent on A then A will always be compiled first....

Comment: It does not really matter, does it? It does not matter because if there is an error in A, B won't be compiled successfully, and to fix entire solution, you have to fix A first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show errors according to their importance, one has to click on the column without title (it should be the first column in errors list, one with error and warning icons).

Answer (score 1):

You can compile projects independently from each other, by rightclick the project and selecting build. So only compile the library, the errors for the projects depending on it will disappear (as they aren't compiled, syntax errors will still show of course). However, you might need to clean the solution first.

Comment: Thank you but this is not a solution really -- dependencies should be resolved automatically, and besides, I really dislike (to put it lightly) such solutions, that human being has to manually do work instead of computer. This is not why we use computers, don't we?

Comment: I don't force you to use this solution.